# How do I fix a corrupted file in Minecraft Pocket Edition 0.9.5?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a big horrible annoying problem, but on my sisters Android Tablet. What happens is: say you press on a world, or new world, then it instantly comes up with 'This is a corrupted file, this world can't load' or something like that. I'm so confused and my sister is really upset about it. I've tried deleting it and re-installing it but it's still the same because it still has the same worlds.

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting some worlds then try again. This happened to me and I deleted some worlds and then it worked.